# Declarar classes locais como públicas

Tags: c++

Olá, tou com um problema que *explode minha cabeça*:

Tou fazendo um script em C++ com o objetivo de fazer um jogo. Tudo ia bem quando acabei num caso que, pelo que pesquisei, não encontrei solução no ST. 1º o script, depois o problema em si:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "finish.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>
#include "enemy.h"
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

finish d;

cout << "Welcome to the most epic game ever!" << "\n\n";

string action;

int rnd;
rnd = d.random_calc(1,2);

switch(rnd){

case 1:

    Monster *enm;
    enm->Encounter(enm->type);
    break;

case 2:

    Ninja *enm;
    enm->Encounter(enm->type);
    break;

}

cout << "Actual life:" /*<<*/   << endl;

Player p(10, 15, enm());
p.actionPrompt(&action, true);

cout << action; 

d.end();

}
```

Para não ocupar muito espaço, segue o link para o [repositório do Github](https://github.com/Victaliorg/CPPTest/tree/master/CPPTest/CPP_Test) para este projeto(Com todas as classes, recomendo vê-las pra ficar mais fácil de me responder)

O problema, afinal. Tenho de escolher, no programa, entre criar uma de duas classes: "Monstro" e "Ninja", ambas derivadas da classe "Inimigo". Agora, recebo erros de compilação quanto às classes criadas, pois elas são criadas como locais(dentro do switch) e não é possível acessá-las fora dele.

Por favor, caso saiba, **Me dê uma solução!**

Comment: *Downvoter*, poderia por favor explicar o motivo ao Pedro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode definir um ponteiro "genérico" para a classe-mãe `Enemy` logo antes do switch: `Enemy *enm`, e dentro do switch faça as devidas instanciações:

```
enm = new Monster();

...

enm = new Enemy();
```

Observe que isso estava faltando de qualquer forma no código original; você não pode simplesmente definir um ponteiro e usá-lo, precisa antes passar um endereço de objeto válido por meio do `new`.

Comment: Aparentemente funcionou! Obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Basta declarar uma variável do tipo **Inimigo** ANTES do **switch** e nos blocos correspondentes você apenas **inicia** a variável, afinal, ela já estará declarada.